# New jOOQ Gradle Plugin can not process self-reference relation correctly

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jooq, jooq-codegen

When switching to the new jOOQ Gradle plugin 3.19.0, another issue I found the former example entity which includes a field refers to itself does not work.

The attempt of upgrading new Gradle plugin is here, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/pull/320

The table that caused the problem.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nodes (
    id UUID NOT NULL /* [jooq ignore start] */ DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() /* [jooq ignore stop] */,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id UUID
);
ALTER TABLE nodes ADD CONSTRAINT nodes_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE nodes ADD CONSTRAINT nodes_parent_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES nodes(id) /* [jooq ignore start] */ON UPDATE CASCADE/* [jooq ignore stop] */;
```

When running `./gradlew clean jooqCodegenMain` command, you will see the following warning message.

```bash
Ambiguous key name       : The database object nodes_parent_fk generates an inbound key method name nodes which conflicts with the previously generated outbound key method name. Use a 
custom generator strategy to disambiguate the types. More information here:
 - https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/
 - https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/
```

But the original version using `nu.studer.jooq` plugin was working well: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/jooq-kotlin-co-gradle

**Update**: just see this warning, it seems the final generated classes worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Starting with jOOQ 3.19, there is now support for [to-many relationship paths](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-to-many-join/). The `DefaultGeneratorStrategy` uses the same naming pattern for `to-many` paths as it does for `to-one` paths. If your table is self-referential, then there's a naming conflict, and the `to-many` path is simply not generated.

You can either:

- [Turn off the feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-implicit-join-paths/) using `implicitJoinPathsToMany = false`
- Ignore the warning
- Implement a generator strategy to disambiguate the name

Note, the `nu.studer.jooq` plugin will also generate this warning, as soon as it supports jOOQ 3.19